# File size limits in Marketing cloud emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, content-builder

Im having troubles finding information (As always regarding marketing cloud) about the file size limits of emails in marketing cloud. Ive looked through [MC Help pages](http://[Window%20Title]%20esif_assist_64.exe%20%20[Main%20Instruction]%20esif_assist_64.exe%20har%20slutat%20att%20fungera%20%20[Content]%20Windows%20s%C3%B6ker%20efter%20en%20l%C3%B6sning%20p%C3%A5%20problemet...%20%20[Avbryt]) but since the search function doesnt work on the help pages I need help finding it.

So my questions are:

What is the size limit of a specific send (the size of an email to be sent)? What is the file size of specific images in an email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Content Builder, you can upload file types up to **5 MB** per file.

Some of the standard file types it supports are below

```
DOCUMENT    IMAGE   AUDIO   VIDEO   ARCHIVE CODE
.csv       .bmp     .mp3    .vi     .gpg    .css
.doc       .gif     .ogg    .mov    .zip    .js
.docx      .jpeg    .wav    .mpeg           .html
.dot       .jpg             .mpg            .xml
.ics       .png             .swf    
.js        .tif             
.mdb       .tiff
```

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_supported_file_types.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

The closest to documentation that exists is the [Portfolio Supported File Types entry](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/portfolio/supported_file_types_in_portfolio/).

In this it tells you the limits are: 200KB for images and 1MB for all other file types.

> The following file types can be imported into your portfolio.
>   Portfolio only accepts images at or less than 200KB in size. Other
>   file types must be 1 MB or less in size.

If you want to use the 'classic editor' I know these limits can be removed or adjusted to your needs, but for Content Builder, they refuse to customize these limits currently. I am fairly sure with a strong enough business case, they may make an exception, but it is not as easily done as it is via classic content - where you just simply contact your rep or global support and ask for it to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, those were the limits i was looking for. I guess that one should focus on using 'content builder' instead of 'classic editor' since that will be phased out?

Comment: Yes and no.  Classic isn't going anywhere for at least another couple years, so it is a viable alternative still, BUT it is not directly compatible with Content Builder. So if you do most of your building of emails, etc in Content Builder, you would have to do extra work to use items stored in Classic Portfolio.

Answer (score -1):

The Email Studio Portfolio size limit is 200Ko.

The Content Builder size limit is 3Mo.

Link to file size and supported file types. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_supported_file_types.htm&type=5

Comment: mind linking the doc from where you are getting the limits for reference purposes? thanks

Comment: The 200Ko for the Portfolio is already refererenced in the previous comments. About Content Builder, there is no documentation. I simply know it because I tested it myself by importing different files from various sizes. I got an error message when files are bigger than 3Mo.

Comment: Just because it is in a previous comment, doesnt mean you should ommit it, if the previous answer were to be removed, then your answer would not be supported. Please take some time to review [answer]. As is your answer is not much different from the Accepted answer, except for the Content builder size limit, which does not have any supporting documentation.

Comment: Hi glls, thanks for your constructive feedback and for letting me know how comments should be written in here. Happy to amend my answer and add the link about the 200Ko limit. However, what would you expect as a "proof" for the 3Mo limit as there is not supporting documentation? Should I share screenshots?

Comment: any kind of proof or link towards a documentation source. if you searched for and did not find any, it is important to mention it, as you might have seen in the accepted answer. Much Appreciated.