# File size limits in Content builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, fileupload

To Content Builder, I can upload video file up to 5 MB per file:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_supported_file_types.htm&type=5

But how do you increase this limit? For example 5 GB.
Couldn't find documentation for this case

Comment: I don't think 5GB is possible but get in touch with AE to increase your account limit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File size limits in Marketing cloud emails](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171282/file-size-limits-in-marketing-cloud-emails)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Content Builder is not a CMS/hosting service. What do you want to do with such a large video file afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard limit and can't be increased.

Why do you need such large files within content builder?